# some javascript is not work in asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div element which is set display to none. However, i want to change it to block when i click a button.

The question is some javascript code is not work in the button.click function.

My code:

```
 <input type="button" id="btnNew" class="btnNew" value="New" />

//javascript
 $("#btnNew").click(function() {
                console.log("show");
                $("#diva").style.display = "block";
            });
```

console result

> 1 show
>
> 2 sample.aspx:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of
>   undefined

However, if i enter `$("#diva").style.display = "block";` in browser console directly, all well done.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$("#diva").show()` or `$("#diva").css('display', 'block')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i have tried it..How can it work if the object is undefined?

Comment: why is the object undefined, `$("#diva")` returns a jQuery object which does not have the style property, that is the reason for your error